# Cannot edit anything in folder

Tags: windows-8

I really don't know how on earth it is still stopping me from editing files in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps... I've tried everything. What is the deal?! I've checked sub folders. EVERYTHING. I have full control over it and I still get "You need permission to preform this action." Which is just adding a file to a folder! I'll screen shot anything to prove I have full rights to this folder.

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you go to the Effective Access tab and enter your username? Ownership and full control permissions are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

More specific rules always take precedence over general ones, maybe there's one that overrides *Full control* inherited from *Administrators* group. Add *Full control* permissions for your specific username.

You can also try to create a file in a folder you have access to, then copy it to the desired location - Explorer treats copying/moving differently than creating new files.

Comment: When copying a folder it will inherit permissions, but when moving it will retain its original permissions, as long as the move is within the same NTFS volume, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316

In that sense it's not completely accurate to say "Explorer treats copying/moving differently than creating new files." - it only treats moving differently to creating new files and only when it's on the same volume.

Comment: @sahmeepee what I meant by saying that "*Explorer treats copying/moving differently than creating new files*" is that it won't let you create a file in a folder that requires elevated privileges, but if you try to create it elsewhere and copy/move it, an UAC prompt will appear and everything will work just fine.